# WSO2 CEP 3.1.0 - How to create custom jms event adaptor?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, adaptor, wso2-cep

I have a question about WSO2 CEP 3.1.0.
Please advice for my question.

There is jms event adaptor for activemq in WSO2 CEP 3.1.0 as defult.
But I need custom event adaptor for message broker such as rabbitmq except for activemq.
So I want to create custom jms event adaptor, and know how to create this custom event adaptor easily.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JMS adaptor which is there in WSO2 CEP is not only for activemq. It supports all the jms brokers but we have not tested with all the brokers. It should work with rabbitmq, you should able work with that.. Anyway If you need to create a custom event adaptor please follow [1]

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/08/writing-custom-event-adaptors-for-cep-3.0.0/

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom adapter example that is RabbitMQ AMQP in/out adpater
https://github.com/javalove93/wso2-rabbitmq-adapter

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help others in the future.